# Good practice to write to a file

Tags: haskell

In the main function of my program, I call timesRule which is returning a Boolean value. In this function I want to write to a file. However, if I understood correctly the function times rule needs to return IO() if it writes to file.
How should I structure my code to write to a file in a function returning a Boolean value ?

```hs
timesRule :: (MultiSet LocalType) -> Bool
timesRule sequent = do 
    let result = MultiSet.concatMap (\x -> if isPrl x then [checkTimes x, checkTimes2 x] else [x] ) sequent
    let file = "tmp/log.txt"
    let content = "TIMES rule: " ++  (show(MultiSet.toList result))
    let log = writeToFile file content
    prefixRule result
```

Used function:

```hs
import qualified System.IO.Strict as SIO

writeToFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO()
writeToFile file content = do 
    x <- SIO.readFile file
    writeFile file ("\n"++content)
    appendFile file x
```

Comment: If your function does any IO at all it needs to return a value of some type `IO a` - in your case `IO Bool` I presume. Note that you then can't use it outside of `IO` - since you're writing to a file, Haskell doesn't allow you to "pretend" that this is an ordinary "pure" function that simply calculates a result.

Comment: Your function, as written, _doesn't_ write to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The somewhat obvious solution would be changing the type your function to `IO Bool` as @Robin Zigmond pointed out.

There is some problem with your syntax apart from calling `writeToFile`, though. For your function `timesRule` to have the given type it would need to look like this:

```
timesRule :: (MultiSet LocalType) -> Bool
timesRule sequent = -- there is no do here
    let 
        result = MultiSet.concatMap (\x -> if isPrl x then [checkTimes x, checkTimes2 x] else [x] ) sequent

        -- the following two lines are superfluous ...
        file = "tmp/log.txt"
        content = "TIMES rule: " ++  (show(MultiSet.toList result))

        -- ... because this still doesn't work
        log = writeToFile file content

        -- ... and what were you going to use `log` for, anyway?
    in  
        prefixRule result
```

Changing your type to `IO Bool` allows you to use monadic do-syntax. `Bool` by itself neither has an applicative nor a monad instance and thus there is no meaningful do-syntax. (In order to have either an applicative or a monad instance, you need a type function like `Maybe` or `IO`, fyi):

```
timesRule :: (MultiSet LocalType) -> IO Bool
timesRule sequent = do
    let 
        result = MultiSet.concatMap (\x -> if isPrl x then [checkTimes x, checkTimes2 x] else [x] ) sequent

        file = "tmp/log.txt"
        content = "TIMES rule: " ++  (show(MultiSet.toList result))

    -- the syntax to get the value of type `a` out of `IO a` is this:
    log <- writeToFile file content

    -- the function to turn a value of type `a` into `IO a` is `pure`:
    pure (prefixRule result)
```

You stil don't use `log` and might as well replace

`log <- writeToFile file content`

with

`writeToFile file content`

Given that `writeToFile` has type `... -> IO ()`, the () is pronounced "unit", the value of log is `()` and thus `log` does not contain any useful information (probably).

---

The less obvious solution is to refactor your code a bit and seperate the concerns. Sometimes it does make sense to have a function write to a file *and* return some boolean value. In your case, you probably want a funcion that returns `result`, i.e. turn this line into a function:

```
MultiSet.concatMap (\x -> if isPrl x then [checkTimes x, checkTimes2 x] else [x] ) sequent
```

Then you already have `prefixRule` that gives you the `Bool` and you have `writeFile`. This way you separate pure code (anything that does not have the type `IO something`) form code with IO-side effects.